# What is the mutable part of an igraph object?

Tags: r, igraph

The igraph documentation mentions the "mutable" part of the igraph object.

I haven't been able to find a discussion of exactly what that is.

from the [documentation](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/igraph/igraph.pdf)

```
identical_graphs:
 Decide if two graphs are identical
Description:
This is similar to identical in the base package, but ignores the mutable 
piece of igraph objects,
that might be different, even if the two graphs are identical.
```

Is that obvious and easy to explain or are there good resources going into the background of this?