# Can two graphs be identical in Igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Can two graphs be identical in Igraph.
For example:

```
library(igraph)
identical(make_ring(0), make_ring(0))
```

returns FALSE.

Comment: See the [identical_graphs](https://igraph.org/r/doc/identical_graphs.html) function in igraph.

Comment: @mikeck You should post your [comment as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment). Simple question, simple answer but that could be useful to others.

Comment: According to the documentation two graphs are identical iff:


"Two graphs are considered identical by this function if and only if they are represented in exactly the same way in the internal R representation. This means that the two graphs must have the same list of vertices and edges, in exactly the same order, with same directedness, and the two graphs must also have identical graph, vertex and edge attributes."

I would expect that two empty graphs should be equal.

Is there an example of identical graphs.

Comment: As @mikeck said, `identical_graphs(make_ring(0), make_ring(0))` gives `TRUE`

Comment: Observe that:
`identical(toString(make_ring(0)), toString(make_ring(0)) )`

gives `TRUE`.

Comment: The documentation you quote is for `identical_graphs` and _not_ for `identical`. Why do you insist on using `identical`? It will not work on graphs for technical reasons (as alluded to in the Details section of the documentation). That is why `identical_graphs` exists.

Comment: I am just curious and not alone. See for example: [What is the mutable part of an igraph object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440039/what-is-the-mutable-part-of-an-igraph-object).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to mask identical() like union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for isomorphic graphs, you should use

```
> is_isomorphic_to(make_ring(10), make_ring(10))
[1] TRUE
```

otherwise, use `identical_graphs` instead if you need them to be strictly the same.